# Angular js bootstrap button disable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following angularjs app html file:

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="open(subcategory)">Add Course <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
```

I would like to know if we can disable the `Add course` button whenever the condition `required credits == completed credits` is met. The controller is a regular json file with all the parameters in the subcategories.

Please help!

Comment: Please reduce your example from your entire app, to a minimized reproduction of your issue.

Comment: Hi thank you for letting me know. I actually saved the edit in a different file but forgot to copy the new copy.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the ng-disabled directive

```
<button class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-disabled="subcategory.required2 == subcategory.completed2" ng-click="open(subcategory)">Add Course <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the isDisabled variable in the controller based on the condition.

```
<button disabled="{{isDisabled}}">Disabled</button>
```

Comment: This won't work in IE8 and below. It interprets disabled="false" as true, hence the ng-disabled directive.

Comment: Also, I don't think you'd need the `scope` keyword in there.